# How can I get the same clientWidth value from IE and chrome?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a scroll function.
I try to refresh the scrolling according to the changed width value.
After zooming in IE, clientWidth value is different than expected.

```js
function btnClick() {
  document.getElementById('tt').style.zoom = 1.5;
  console.log(document.getElementById('gg').clientWidth);
}

function btn2Click() {
  document.getElementById('tt').style.zoom = 1;
  console.log(document.getElementById('gg').clientWidth);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" onclick="btnClick()" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="click2" onclick="btn2Click()" />
<div id="ee" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="tt" style="width: 100%; height:100%">
    <div id="gg" style="width: 100%; height:44px; background: black">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I should only use javascript instead of jQuery.

Click btn.
try get clientWidth,

```
document.getElementById('gg').clientWidth;
```

Chrome and IE values ​​are different.
In IE, I want to get the same result as Chrome.
How do I get the changed width value?

Comment: i also came across this problem. it was mozilla in my case. had to resort to jqeury. if you can use jquery, i recommend switching to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the browser's box model. Use something like jQuery or another JavaScript abstraction library to normalise the DOM model.

The equivalent of clientHeight and clientWidth in jquery is

```
$(window).width(), $(window).height()
```